# How is the arc length equation in radians derived from that in degrees?

Tags: geometry

Arc length $l$ can be calculated either by degrees or radians:

$l = 2\pi r \times \dfrac{\theta}{360} \text{ (in degrees)}$

$l = r\theta \text{ (in radians)}$

We can multiply the degree equation by $\dfrac{180}{\pi}$ and obtain the radian equation.

However, when we convert a $\theta$ in degrees to radians, we multiply it by $\dfrac{\pi}{180}$ instead. $\dfrac{180}{\pi}$ is used to convert radians to degrees.

I'm sure there's some reasoning behind but I can't seem to figure it out...

Comment: You do get the same results for 90 degrees and $\pi/2$ radians, don't you?

Comment: Your first equation seems wrong. An it is better if you use two different symbols for the measure in radiants and in degree, e.g. $x$ radians and $\alpha$ degree.... so you can avoid confusion.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Fixed it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that a measure of $2\pi$ radians corresponds to $360$ degree, so , if $\theta_r$ is the measure in radiant and $\theta °$ is the measure in degree of the same angle  we have the proportion:
$$
\theta_r : \theta°=2\pi : 360°
$$
(note that this is true because  the two scales are proportional)
from which we have:
$$
\theta_r=\theta ° \frac{2 \pi}{360}
$$

and the length of the arc is
$$
l= r \theta_r= r \theta ° \frac{2 \pi}{360}
$$

Comment: Thank you! This clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

We know from geometry that the circumference $C$ of a circle with radius $r$ is

$$C=2\pi r.$$

> **Definition.** Say a circle is located at the origin. Look at an arc whose length is exactly one radius. The angle of this sector with the positive x-axis is then exacly one radian. See [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/radian.html) for an animation.

So if the arc length is $r$, the angle is $1 \ \mathrm{rad}.$ The angle of the entire circle is thus $2\pi$ times one radian.

$$\theta_{\text{entire circle}}=360^\circ=2\pi \  \mathrm{rad}.$$

Dividing by two,

$$\tag{*}\theta_{\text{half-circle}}=180^\circ=\pi \  \mathrm{rad}. $$

One degree is therefore

$$1^\circ=\frac{\pi}{180}\  \mathrm{rad}.$$

From $(*)$ you can derive the opposite relationship as well. Note also that usually the $\mathrm{rad}$ is put into parentheses or dropped altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually understand the relationship between degrees and radians, and that's why I am confused that transforming the arc length equation actually does the opposite of transforming an angle (i.e. angle in degree to radians: multiply by $\pi$/180; arc length equation in degree to radians: multiply by 180/$\pi$).

Comment: Now I got it, thanks anyway!

Comment: No problem. Glad we could help.